# Using outside links and tabs in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I am using bootstrap tabs on an html page I am working on. I am trying to have the tabs open automatically when clicking on a hyperlink on a different page. How would I go about making this work?

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        Content
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane fade in">
        Content
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <p>Content1</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane fade in">
        <p>Content2</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Even thought I don't have it typed above, I do have the tabs and content wrapped in a container.

Comment: You can simply do that with setting target="_blank" for an example check this.https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_a_target